# Looping through XML content with formatting

Tags: xml, xslt

Given the following XML code:

```
<section>
<p>Text...</p>
<p>More text...</p>
<special>Text with formatting</special>
<p>More text..</p>
</section>
```

I want to use XSLT to output this - but the `<special>` tag must be with the HTML tag `<pre></pre>` around it.

Can't figure out how to make it appear in the right order with all ofte p-elements inside the section. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you could do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="special">
  <xsl:element name="pre">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The crucial bit is the xsl:element that constructs the new element "pre" that you need.

In future questions, please take the time to show what you have *tried* so far. Instead of merely saying you could not get it to work.

Comment: Thank you. I was using a for-each-structure that didnt work well, and I will keep what you said in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and then add templates for the elements needing special treatment e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="special">
  <pre>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </pre>
</xsl:template>
```